# Enable Third party Cookies Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, third-party-cookies

I am using okta as sso, so when i open webpage in incognito mode and try to login using okta incognito mode restrict to store third party cookies for my website and okta session is not created.
After enabling third party cookies by clicking on eye icon on url bar it's working,

But Is there anyway in javascript through which we can programmatically enable third party cookies ?

Comment: No, of course there isn't. If there was, then every shady "advertiser" would immediately turn it on, so that they can track & invade privacy even more.

Comment: Thanks Man!! I know there is no way to do that, but I was looking for some kind of hack  Basically i want to enable third party cookies on button click, but i think there is no hack to achieve it. 

let me know if you have any idea about it !